# Increase dragging-folder-opening speed

Tags: macos, finder, gui

When I want to go and drop a file from my Desktop dir into a given directory that is many levels deep, I typically click on the file and drag it into finder and allow the folders to open themselves along the way and drop it in the target dir.  However, when I need to drop a file in a dir that is 8 levels deep the full second delay for each folder to open makes this a hassle.  Is there any system-level way to configure this to be instantaneous so I am limited only by my dragging speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to speed up, is to increase the speed of the folders opening up.

**OS X Yosemite and earlier**

Go to *Finder > Preferences* > Adjust the speed in Spring-loading delay

**OS X El Capitan**

Go *System Preferences > System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad*

See the full details here in [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189525/spring-loaded-folder-settings-missing-in-yosemite)